# Animations aren't playing

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a problem with my Roblox combat system. The problem is that my Animations don't play when I play them. Here are the scripts:

Client Script

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local Debounce = 0.5
local Keybind = Enum.KeyCode.F
local CanPunch = true

local count = 1
local Animations = 
    {
        script:WaitForChild("PunchAnim"),
        script:WaitForChild("PunchAnim2")
    }

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input, busy)
    if Input.KeyCode == Keybind and not busy then
        print("Keybind Check")
        if CanPunch == true then
            print("CanPunch Check")
            CanPunch = false
            
            local Anim = char.Humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimation(Animations[count])
            Anim:Play()
            Anim.Looped = false
            count = (count%#Animations) + 1
            print("Anim Played")
            
            game.ReplicatedStorage.remotes.Punch:FireServer(player, char)
            print("Fired Event")
            
            wait(Debounce)
            CanPunch = true
        end
    end
    
end)
```

Server Script

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        
        hitbox = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
        hitbox.Size = Vector3.new(4,4,4)
        hitbox.CanCollide = false
        hitbox.Transparency = 1

        local weld = Instance.new("Weld", hitbox)
        weld.Part0 = char.HumanoidRootPart
        weld.Part1 = hitbox
        weld.C1 = CFrame.new(0,0,4)
    end)
        
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.remotes.Punch.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, char)
    
    for i, v in pairs(workspace:GetPartsInPart(hitbox)) do
        if v.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and v.Parent ~= char and v.Parent:FindFirstChild("Hit"..player.Name) == nil then
            
            local Debounce = Instance.new("IntValue", v.Parent)
            Debounce.Name = "Hit"..player.Name
            game.Debris:AddItem(Debounce, 0.25)
            
            v.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):TakeDamage(7.5)
        end
    end
    
    
end)
```

In the script, I'm telling the Animations to play after F is pressed but when I press it in the game, it doesn't play the animation.

I made this script by watching various tutorials to make my own combat system. I've tried fixing the code by re-watching the tutorials as well as reading the roblox documentation to find a solution but I couldn't find one.
I'm new to Lua and I apologize in advance if this is a very easy and basic question, but all help is appreciated. Also, please point out any other mistake in my script. Thanks.

If you see this question, please answer it if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of my question was, that the animations were R6 but my character was R15. I went and changed the game settings and made it so the game only supported R6.